# Does changing the MX records on Tucows DNS affect POP/IMAP?

Tags: office365, exchange, imap, pop3, exchange-online

**Scenario**: My company have email hosted by the ISP with a business domain. The DNS is hosted on Tucows. I have full access to the DNS. The ISP emails only work as POP3 or IMAP.

I want to migrate to the Microsoft 365 emails and I am keeping the same domain. I have the tenant setup on Microsoft website and the domain has been verified with a TXT record but I have yet to change the MX records.

**Question**: If I change the MX records, will the incoming email be diverted to the Microsoft server (once the DNS propagation has completed) or will I need to cancel the email services with the ISP to force the emails to go to the Microsoft side?

Also, will I be able to access the old POP/IMAP emails after changing the MX records (before terminating the services)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **If I change the MX records, will the incoming email be diverted to the Microsoft server (once the DNS propagation has completed):**

   Yes. Remote email services use the MX record to tell where to send email for that domain.
2. **Will I be able to access the old pop/imap emails after changing the MX records (before terminating the services)?**

   Technically, yes. Access to the old mailboxes does not use an MX record.

It depends on the mail service/client, but [most use an SRV record](https://serverfault.com/a/814718/411612) to determine where the mailboxes are stored, like `_autodiscover._tcp.example.com` or `_imap._tcp.example.com`.

If you change that SRV record, then you may have to specify the mail server in your IMAP client manually, or lose access to the old service. As long as the old service is not *also* Microsoft 365, you should be able to have both up at the same time.

Comment: The old service is an inhouse mail server and doesn't use anything other than POP or IMAP, definitely not Microsoft.

I do not have an SRV record for the domain but I will be changing the MX record to microsoft's which would b autodiscover.domain.com

Comment: @DhrumitPatel When you add a mailbox from that service to a client like Outlook, you probably specify a server by IP or DNS name? If you use DNS there, then the clients are using A/AAAA/CNAME type records, and changing your MX record will not break that either

Comment: Agree with @Cpt.Whale.  You will be able to access the old POP/IMAP emails after changing the MX records, as long as you have the correct credentials and settings for your ISP email accounts.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: It has been completed. This can be marked resolved.